# Non-ideal velocity distribution of gases

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

A [recent question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91402/why-is-the-speed-of-ideal-gases-mass-dependent-while-the-kinetic-energy-is-not/91403?noredirect=1#comment167618_91403) about the velocity distribution of ideal gas molecules got me wondering. How much would the velocity distribution vary for non-ideal gases?

I was wondering about a mixture of ethane and helium. The ethane molecule would have vibrational modes that the helium atom wouldn't have. Given that the helium velocity was "ideal," how non-ideal could/would the ethane velocity be?

Some other molecule been experimentally analyzed like this? I guess that a molecule with even more atoms would have even more vibrational/rotational modes.

Comment: Vibrational modes alone would not make the velocity distribution non-ideal.

Comment: @IvanNeretin In ethane, the forces of attraction will obviously be more than that for He. Wouldn’t this make it a non-ideal situation?

Comment: A non-ideal situation? Yes. But a non-ideal velocity distribution? Why?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I’m confused. By “ideal” velocity distribution OP means Maxwell’s velocity distribution right? If it is so, that was derived for ideal gases and there will be deviations for non ideal situation.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: >"The Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution applies to the classical ideal gas, which is an idealization of real gases. In real gases, there are various effects (e.g., van der Waals interactions, vortical flow, relativistic speed limits, and quantum exchange interactions) that can make their speed distribution different from the Maxwell–Boltzmann form."

Comment: To begin with, ideal gas molecules don't have size and don't collide with each other, hence they definitely **would not** establish Maxwell’s velocity distribution. (I don't care if Wikipedia says otherwise.) Sure, it was derived from certain approximations, but these were **not** what we normally call an ideal gas. As for the rest, well, OK, there would be some marginal difference for the molecules which are currently under the influence of (read: in a collision or a close fly-by with) other molecules, but these form only a tiny fraction of all molecules at any given moment.

Comment: Boltzmann's statistics (which do not exist) are used in calculating the velocity distribution,  however, if low pressure or high temperature are assumed then Bose-Einstein/Fermi-Dirac statistics revert to Boltzmann.  The (translational) partition function is calculated and from this the velocity distribution.  If your two species do not interact with one another then the two distribution are independent and will only differ due to mass.  Since equilibrium  exist,  if one type of molecule interacts  to form dimers eg. as $\ce{A_2 <=> 2A}$  then we might consider them as two species.